# Different bibliographies for each chapter with shared references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker, subdividing

I tried to go through already posted solutions but I was not able to find one working for my case. I am compiling a ph.d. thesis with one main file, by including chapters. The format is the following

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}
{\sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitle]{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\usepackage[semicolon,round,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{epsfig}         
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{grffile}        
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm

\begin{document}
\input{chapters/titlepage}

\mainmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/chap0}

\chapter{chap1}
\input{chapters/chap1}

\chapter{chap2}
\input{chapters/chap2}

\end{document}
```

Each chapter has its respective bibliography at the end, as follows

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{chapters/bib0}
```

in the case of chap0. Note that each chapter cannot be compiled alone, since it starts with `\section{}`, and no `\begin{document}`. However, things work well only for the first `\input{ }`, i.e. only for chapter 0. From chapter1 onwards I get just the bibliography of chapter0 repeating. THerefore I get ?? as output in the text for new references. Warnings say that ref'x' is multiple defined and, later, that ref`x` is not defined. How can I fix that ?

Bibtek files are as follows:

bib0

```
@article{acemoglu2000,
title={The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
author={Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
year={2000},
institution={National bureau of economic research}
}

@book{acemoglu2012,
title={Why nations fail: the origins of power, prosperity and poverty},
author={Acemoglu, Daron and Robinson, James A and Woren, Dan},
volume={4},
year={2012},
publisher={SciELO Chile}
}
```

bib1

```
@article{acemoglu2000,
title={The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
author={Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
year={2000},
institution={National bureau of economic research}
}
@article{ackerberg2006,
title={Structural identification of production functions},
author={Ackerberg, Daniel and Caves, Kevin and Frazer, Garth},
year={2006}
}
```

Compile goes as follow: pdflatek -> biblatek -> pdflatek(x2). Looks like it is the only compiling solution working

Comment: You must use `\include` and not `\input` when using `chapterbib` (move the chapter commands in the files) or add a `cbunit` environment, see the documentation. Another solution is to switch to biblatex/biber. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=chapbib

Comment: whenever I use \include it compiles but I get no bibliography at all

Comment: Did you run bibtex on every included file? (biblatex/biber is naturally much more confortable and powerful).

Comment: I did, I get a lot of warnings telling me that it does not find any database for almost all entries, even the ones of chapter0 which is the one working (apparently) properly. ANd I still get multiply defined warnings

Comment: Then you probably got confused because of the relative pathes. Did you call bibtex as `bibtex chapters/chap0` from the location of the main file or as `bibtex chap0`?

Comment: I ran bibtex on every single chap in ´chapters/´

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: not relevant to the question, but ... there are duplicates in the `\usepackage` list (`soul`, `epsfig`, `graphicx`/`graphics`), and `hyperref` should usually come last, with very few (and documented) exceptions.  finally, the line that looks like it is for the `geometry` package ends abruptly and incomplete.

Comment: Probably I did not get your question, I am sorry. I am not that proficient with latex. What I did is compiling from the main file, which implies pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex. Does this answer your question?
Thanks for the duplicates advice. I will try to fix that as well

Answer (score 23, accepted):

References will not be generated as required because of the incorrect usage of `\chapterbib` with `natbib`. The correct usage is:

```
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

When `natbib` is not being used as the citation manager, the usage of `\chapterbib` for references at the end of each chapter is:

```
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
```

This is the complete file to generate the list of references at the end of each chapter based on the code that was uploaded. A few commands from the original file are suppressed for convenience. To avoid getting orphan chapter headings I moved the `\chapter` commands inside the included files. I also deleted the paths to the `included` and `bib` files for simplicity.

Remember to run the compiler (`PDFLaTeX`) on the main file which will generate auxiliary (`aux`) files for each included file. Then open each auxiliary file and run `bibtex` on each of those files. This will generate `bbl` files for each chapter. Then go back to the main file and rerun the compiler twice.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
%\newpagestyle{mystyle}
%{\sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitle]{}{}{\thepage}}
%\pagestyle{mystyle}\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Don't use this                                               %
%\usepackage[semicolon,round,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib} %
%\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}                           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Replacement                                                  %
\usepackage[semicolon,round,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}  %
\usepackage{chapterbib}                                        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{epsfig}         
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{grffile}        
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry} % this was incomplete
\usepackage{filecontents}
% Create bib file for Introduction chapter
\begin{filecontents*}{bib0.bib}
@article{acemoglu2000,
    title={The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
    author={Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
    year={2000},
    institution={National bureau of economic research}
}
@book{acemoglu2012,
    title={Why nations fail: the origins of power, prosperity and poverty},
    author={Acemoglu, Daron and Robinson, James A and Woren, Dan},
    volume={4},
    year={2012},
    publisher={SciELO Chile}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
% Create bib file for chapter 1. Note that it is not a requirement to have different bib files for each chapter.
\begin{filecontents*}{bib1.bib}
@article{acemoglu2000,
    title={The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
    author={Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
    year={2000},
    institution={National bureau of economic research}
}
@article{ackerberg2006,
    title={Structural identification of production functions},
    author={Ackerberg, Daniel and Caves, Kevin and Frazer, Garth},
    year={2006}
}
%
%Create Introduction
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap0.tex}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    This is Chapter ``Introduction'' from included file chap0.tex. \\
    This is a citation for \cite{acemoglu2000} from bib0. \\
    \citep{acemoglu2012} is a citation for the second reference. \\
    The Reference list for introductory chapter appears next. \\
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{bib0}
\end{filecontents*}
%
% Create Chapter 1
\begin{filecontents*}{chap1.tex}
    \chapter{chap1}
    This is Chapter 1 from included file chap1.tex. \\
    This is a citation for \cite{acemoglu2000} from bib1. \\
    \citep{ackerberg2006} is a citation for the second reference. \\
    The Reference list for the chapter appears next. \\
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{bib1}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Suppress content not required for this solution %  
%\include{chapters/titlepage}                    %
%                                                %
%\mainmatter                                     %
%\tableofcontents                                %
%\listoffigures                                  %
%\listoftables                                   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{chap0}
\include{chap1}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the output for Chapter Introduction]

[image: This is the output for Chapter 1]

Comment: I tried with Texmaker, Texstudio but still, I don't get the aux file. it says chapterbib.sty bot found.

Comment: Unfortunately `subfiles` appears to be incompatible with `chapterbib`.

Comment: I am getting an error message like: `Illegal, another \bibstyle command : \bibstyle : {apalike} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command`  when running your code on Overleaf (and locally on texmaker)?

Answer (score 5):

For those who uses `biblatex` instead of `natbib` just put your chapter inside the `refsection` environment. Here is an example using the same code as Ross.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%Declaring the way I use Biblatex. You should change the params depending on %your styles
\usepackage[style=abnt,uniquename=init,giveninits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib0.bib}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% Create bib file for Introduction chapter
\begin{filecontents*}{bib0.bib}
@article{acemoglu2000,
    title={The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
    author={Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
    year={2000},
    institution={National bureau of economic research}
}
@book{acemoglu2012,
    title={Why nations fail: the origins of power, prosperity and poverty},
    author={Acemoglu, Daron and Robinson, James A and Woren, Dan},
    volume={4},
    year={2012},
    publisher={SciELO Chile}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
% Create bib file for chapter 1. Note that it is not a requirement to have different bib files for each chapter.
\begin{filecontents*}{bib1.bib}
@article{acemoglu2000,
    title={The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
    author={Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
    year={2000},
    institution={National bureau of economic research}
}
@article{ackerberg2006,
    title={Structural identification of production functions},
    author={Ackerberg, Daniel and Caves, Kevin and Frazer, Garth},
    year={2006}
}
%
%Create Introduction
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap0.tex}
%This is how you'd go if you use Biblatex
\begin{refsection}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    This is Chapter ``Introduction'' from included file chap0.tex. \\
    This is a citation for \cite{acemoglu2000} from bib0. \\
    \citep{acemoglu2012} is a citation for the second reference. \\
    The Reference list for introductory chapter appears next. \\
    \printbibliography
    \end{refsection}
\end{filecontents*}
%
% Create Chapter 1
\begin{filecontents*}{chap1.tex}
    \begin{refsection}
    \chapter{chap1}
    This is Chapter 1 from included file chap1.tex. \\
    This is a citation for \cite{acemoglu2000} from bib1. \\
    \citep{ackerberg2006} is a citation for the second reference. \\
    The Reference list for the chapter appears next. \\
    \printbibliography
    \end{refsection}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Suppress content not required for this solution %  
%\include{chapters/titlepage}                    %
%                                                %
%\mainmatter                                     %
%\tableofcontents                                %
%\listoffigures                                  %
%\listoftables                                   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{chap0}
\include{chap1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the TeX primitive input with the LaTeX command \include. Then you can select the sections to compile with the LaTeX command \includeonly{chapters/chap0}. The LaTeX include mechanism automatically takes care of cross references.

You will have to re-organise your input a little, because \include forces a page break (and you don't want a page break immediately after a chapter heading).

Comment: thanks for the answer. whenever I use \include it compiles but I get no bibliography at all

Comment: Make sure that you run BibTeX on the right files; when you \include{chapters/chap1}, run bibtex chapters/chap1 &c.

Comment: @Bob:  it's TexStudio's problem.  This hack lets TexStudio run bibtex on each included file:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297430/how-to-run-bibtex-in-texstudio-or-otherwise-on-included-files

Comment: @jknappen I have the same issue as Bob - compiles but no bibliography at all. I receive a warning of undefined citation for all references. I am using Overleaf and not sure if and how bibtex should be run there

Comment: @Andreuccio Are you using `\include{}` instead of `\input{}`? Also, are the `\bibliographystyle{}  \bibliography{}` commands inside the files to be included? I am using overleaf too and after these two considerations I had no troubles in implementing the @Ross useful answer