# Book class does not recognise the references in the bib file?

Tags: citing, natbib, author-number

I am trying to create my first book using `book`-class. I have successfully included chapters and the reference pages of each chapter are shown flawlessly. However, for some reason my citations in the main text don't work - for example, instead Sims (2003), I get **author ?**. I have tried numerous things but can't figure out, why is this happening - would appreciate a lot, if someone could help.

Here is a piece of code that I find relevant:

The main `thesis.tex` file that includes chapters:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}
    \usepackage{chapterbib}
    \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{epigraph}
    \usepackage{xr}

    \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
    %\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
    %\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
    %\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
    %\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
    %\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
    \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

    %\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter  
    %\pagenumbering{roman} 
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter 
    %\pagenumbering{arabic} 
    \include{tex/chapter1}\newpage\cleardoublepage
    %\input{tex/chapter2}\newpage\cleardoublepage
    %\input{tex/chapter3}\newpage\cleardoublepage
    %\input{tex/chapter4}\newpage\cleardoublepage
    %\input{tex/chapter5}\newpage\cleardoublepage

    \end{document}
```

Inside chapters I call references page by:

```
    \renewcommand\bibname{{REFERENCES}}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
    \bibliography{tex/references}
```

Inside chapter texts I cite in the following way:

```
    \citet{Weibull2007}
```

While the corresponding entry in the bib file references looks like:

```
    @ARTICLE{Weibull2007,
      author = {Jorgen W. Weibull and Lars-Goran Mattsson and Mark                 Voorneveld},
      title = {Better May be Worse: Some Monotonicity Results and Paradoxes in Discrete Choice Under Uncertainty},
      journal = {Theory and Decision},
      year = {2007},
      volume = {63},
      month = {September},
       timestamp = {2016.06.26}
    }
```

As an output of this citation I get: (**author?**) [54] study

More information on the chapter setups:

```
\chapter[Content title ]{}
\title{Title}

\begin{center}
\huge{Title}
\footnote{text}

\large{author\footnote{
text}}

\vspace*{2cm}
    \end{center}

\begin{center}
    \textmd{Abstract}
\end{center}
text



\newpage

\section{Introduction}
 text. cite{author1} text.\citep{author2} text. \ref{Sec: Model1} text.
 \section{Section two}
  text. \citeauthor{author3}.
\section{Conclusion}
text

\renewcommand\bibname{{REFERENCES}} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\bibliography{tex/Citation}  
\begin{appendices}
    \appendixpage
    \noappendicestocpagenum
    \addappheadtotoc
\section{one}
text
\section{two}
text
\end{appendices}
```

Does anybody see the problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Best,

Mark

Comment: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: Did you run the cycle `(pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: use `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`. `\citet` and `\citep` depends upon style.

Comment: I see a lot of inaccessible `\input{....}` statements -- this is not a compilable document!

Comment: Off-topic: All `\newpage\cleardoublepage` statements are probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you should (a) use the `plainnat` bibliography style instead of the `plain` bibliography style and (b) load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`. That way, you can  produce author-number style citation call-outs via `\citet` and purely numeric-style citation call-outs via `\citep`.

Separately, since you're using the `chapterbib` package to create per-chapter bibliographies while employing section-level rather than chapter-level per-chapter bibliographies, you should (a) load `natbib` with the option `sectionbib` (in addition to the option `numbers` -- see above) and (b) `\include` rather than `\input` the `chapterx.tex` files. (See page 4 of the user guide of the `chapterbib` package.) Provide `\bibliographystyle` instructions in each `chapterx.tex` file. After the initial LaTeX run, there will be separate `chapterx.aux` files (in addition to the `\jobname.aux` file.) Run BibTeX separately on each of the chapter aux files, by typing `bibtex chapter1`, `bibtex chapter2`, etc -- one per chapter. You may have to open a command window and run bibtex manually. Then, run LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

[image]

TWo additional suggestions/observations:

- As you're using the `book` document class, do use high-level commands such as `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` instead of low-level instructions such as `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.
- Do make sure that all information in your bib entries is correct and complete. E.g., in the Weibull2007 entry, two fields (`number` and `pages`) were missing and the first names of two of the authors were missing diacritics.

---

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@ARTICLE{Weibull2007,
  author = {J{\"o}rgen W. Weibull and Lars-G{\"o}ran 
            Mattsson and Mark Voorneveld},
  title  = {Better May be Worse: {Some} Monotonicity 
            Results and Paradoxes in Discrete Choice 
            Under Uncertainty},
  journal= {Theory and Decision},
  year   = {2007},
  volume = {63},
  number = {2},
  month  = {September},
  pages  = {121-151},
  timestamp = {2016.06.26}
}    
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter1.tex}
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\chapter{Introduction}
\citet{Weibull2007}, \citep{Weibull2007}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter2.tex}
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\citep{Weibull2007}, \citet{Weibull2007}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}  %% <-- note this change
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%\usepackage{amssymb} %% don't load packages more than once!
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{setspace}   %% again: don't load packages more than once!
\usepackage{xr}         %% are you sure you need this package?!

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
%    \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
%    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
%    \addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
%    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
%    \addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

 %% <-- note this change
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%%%\pagenumbering{roman} 
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
%%%\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico. Thanks a lot, I've incorporated your changes and it solved some problems but not all. I have almost the same situation as your example, but the difference is that I have more chapters. It seems as, when I am compiling bibliography, it only compiles the first bib file. Therefore, the first chapter compiles nicely with all the references being correct. The other chapters have (**author?**) or just **?** for every reference that was not defined in the first chapter. Is there a way to tell tex to consider every chapter's bibliography separately? Tnx a lot!

@Bernard Yes I did, see above

Comment: @Mark - Did you follow the instructions on p. 4 of the user guide of the `chapterbib` package? (Type `texdoc chapterbib` at a command prompt to launch the user guide in a pdf viewer.)

Comment: -As far as I've understood 'chapterbib' user guide, I should change '\input' to '\include' and move '\bibliographystyle{plainnat}' from the main .tex file to the chapters with respect to my above setup. However, this turns all of my citations to **?** (even when I compile a single chapter). I have also tried using '\cbinput' instead '\include' but again the same thing. I have changed the posting to include a more detailed information (skipping the middle of a chapter for which I believe is irrelevant- figures, subsections etc.). Thank you again!

Comment: @Mark - In addition, you need to run BibTeX not on `\jobname` but separately (probably manually) on `chapter1`, `chapter2`, etc -- one per `\include`d file. Then, run LaTeX twice more on `\jobname`. I'll update my example to highlight this requirement.

Comment: When using Chapterbib with Natbib, the correct setup is `\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}`
`\usepackage{chapterbib}` See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229846/different-bibliographies-for-each-chapter-with-shared-references/300144#300144

Comment: @Ross - Thanks, I've updated the code. (Incidentally, my initial code works just fine too, but it's probably prudent to follow the instructions in sections 2.15 and 2.15.1 of the user guide of the natbib package...)

Comment: So, I've done as instructed. The error i get when compiling the `bibtex chapter1` command (after i compiled `pdflatex Thesis` -`Thesis` is a `\jobname`) is `I couldn't open the database file tex/references`. (Chapter1 is also in the `tex` directory.) Therefore, the bibliography environment stays empty. If however I replace the `\include` with `\input` in the above updated posting (which reflects the current situation of my code), and move the `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` from `chapter1` to `Thesis`, I can successfully run, but only with one chapter. I feel the problem might be in `\include`?

Comment: As it turns out, the problem was in directory. I've put my Thesis.tex in the main directory, and chapers are at \tex\chapter1. When I ran from the cmd I first used the following sequence: pdflatex Thesis, cd tex, bibtex chapter1, cd .., pdflatex Thesis, pdflatex Thesis. 

Don't quite understand why, but it did not work when I would change directory to run the bibtex files - I guess that the pdflatex than fails to give message to bib but I am not sure. If I run everything from the main directory (e.g. bibtex tex\chapter1) everything works. Thanks!!