# Bibliography in each chapter

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker

Good evening.

I'm writing my thesis and I want to put a bibliography in each chapter. for that, I use the package `\usepackage{chapterbib}` and at the end of each chapter I define the concerned bibliography.

But when I compile, I get the first bibliography repeated at the end of each chapters knowing that I give each bibliograhy a specific name.

Please can you help me. Thank you

Comment: you mind sharing your code with us?

Comment: If you're using `chapterbib`, you're not actually using `biblatex` are you (as the tag suggests)?

Comment: no i'm using chapterbib @Torbjørn T

Comment: But are you using biblatex? Or the old BiBTeX?

Comment: I'm using Bibtex @PeterFlynn

Comment: @PeterFlynn [`chapterbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib) and [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) are incompatible so if [`chapterbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib) is being used that information is sufficient to be sure that [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is not being used.

Comment: Not me, OP is "A H"

Comment: This might help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300144. Users of 'chapterbib' often overlook that you must run BibTeX on the 'aux' file for each chapter.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

I'd use package `bibunits` if you have to use old BiBTeX, eg (call this `test.tex`)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\title{My Thesis}
\author{A N Other}
\maketitle
\begin{bibunit}[ieeetr]
  \chapter{Intro}
  Text \cite{flynn2009}
  \putbib[test]
\end{bibunit}
\begin{bibunit}[vancouver]
  \chapter{Research}
  Text \cite{flynn2013}
  \putbib[test]
\end{bibunit}
\begin{bibunit}[acm]
  \chapter{Conclusion}
  Text \cite{flynn2016}
  \putbib[test]
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

Run with something that automates the process such as `latexmk`, using this as your test.bib, eg `latexmk -gg -pdf -bibtex test`

```
@inproceedings{flynn2009,
  author     = {Peter Flynn},
  title      = {{Why writers don't use \textsc{xml}: 
  The usability of editing software for structured documents}},
  series     = {{Balisage---The Markup Conference (11--14 August)}},
  year   = {2009},
  address    = {Montr\'{e}al, \textsc{qc}},
  publisher      = {Balisage Series on Markup Technologies},
  volume     = {3},
  url    = {http://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol3/html/Flynn01/BalisageVol3-Flynn01.html}
}

@inproceedings{flynn2013,
  author     = {Peter Flynn},
  title      = {{Markup to generate markup to generate markup}},
  subtitle   = {Using \textsc{xml} to create and maintain
  \LaTeX{} packages and classes},
  series     = {{Balisage---The Markup Conference (6--9 August 2013)}},
  year   = {2013},
  address    = {Montréal, \textsc{qc}},
  publisher      = {Balisage Series on Markup Technologies},
  volume     = {10},
  url    = {http://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol10/html/Flynn01/BalisageVol10-Flynn01.html}
}

@book{flynn2016,
  author     = {Peter Flynn},
  title      = {{Formatting Information}},
  publisher      = {Silmaril},
  address    = {Cork, Ireland},
  year   = {2016},
  month      = {April},
  url    = {http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/}
}
```

P