# Why does chapterbib include references from the entire document at the end of each chapter/section?

Tags: bibliographies, chapterbib

I'm making a document that has a bibliography at the end of each section and a global bibliography at the end. Logically, the bibliography at the end of each section should only contain citations that were referenced *in that section*. The global bibliography should contain every reference that is cited throughout the document. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{cbunit}
\section{something}
First discuss \cite{goossens93}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mwecitations}
\end{cbunit}


\begin{cbunit}
\section{something else}
Now discuss \cite{rothstein2011unemployment} and \cite{fujita2010economic}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mwecitations}
\end{cbunit}


\renewcommand{\refname}{Global bibliography}
\bibliography{mwecitations}

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image: Output document from this MWE]

The citations file `mwecitations.bib` is:

```
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@article{fujita2010economic,
  title={Economic effects of the unemployment insurance benefit},
  author={Fujita, Shigeru},
  journal={FRB Phil. Business Review},
  volume={4},
  year={2010}
}
@article{rothstein2011unemployment,
  title={Unemployment insurance and job search in the {Great Recession}},
  author={Rothstein, Jesse},
  journal={NBER},
  volume={w17534},
  year={2011}
}
```

Why are all citations from the entire document included in the bibliography that follows each section? The document *should* look like this (pardon my less-than-elegant edits).

[image: Desired output from this MWE]

I compile these files with Xelatex and Biblatex. From [the documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cite/chapterbib.pdf), I think I'm using `cbunit` correctly.

Comment: Imho to get this working chapterbib would need separate files that you `\include`. You could try bibunits instead, but I would suggest to use biblatex/biber.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My interpretation of [the documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cite/chapterbib.pdf) is that separate files aren't strictly necessary. From point 3: "Without `\include`: If you can’t use `\include` ... ,  then you  can  use `\begin{cbunit} ... \end{cbunit}`
(for  everything  in  one  file)." Am I interpreting this incorrectly?

Comment: Imho the documenation is either wrong or misleading. But why don't you want to use biblatex? It is much more powerful, and such things work with refsegments directly.

Comment: I just checked a work I have done with separate bibliography... I had to run bibtex in every chapter before runing in the main document. Checked that otherwise doesn't work. I will check it with your code too... may be the chaprers(sections) have to be seperated and just one bib file to be ok

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I misread your first comment. You're saying that I could just use biblatex/biber/natbib together instead of chapterbib? I have no problems with that solution; I'm just not familiar with how biber works, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Don't use natbib with biblatex.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300144. Note how to combine 'natbib' with 'chapterbib'.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I may have to ask another question about biblatex/biber/bibunits. Even the [simple examples from the documentation](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/bibunits/bibunits.pdf) for bibunits don't work for me (the inline citations are blank). It's quite frustrating!

Comment: Don't use biblatex together with bibunits. Beside this "don't work" is not a good problem description. Make a new question, show the example you are trying and describe *exactly* all the compilation steps you are doing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer [Done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389523/41317).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, cbunit grouping doesn't facilitate using bibtex; it is only useful for manually compiled bibliographies. The documentation is rather cryptic on the point, but hints at it.

To use bibtex and have no page breaks between the bib groupings, you should use `\cbinput`, with with groupings in separate files. Be sure to run it according to the instructions (item 3): use the `[draft]` option (package or document); run latex; run bibtex on each file that was `\cbinput`; remove the `[draft]` option and run latex.

The `[draft]` option basically uses `\include` instead of `\input` so that separate `.aux` files get generated for bibtex to use.