# How do I include a global bibliography at the end of the document with bibunits?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, bibunits

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[globalcitecopy]{bibunits}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{filecontents*}{mwecitations.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@article{fujita2010economic,
    title={Economic effects of the unemployment insurance benefit},
    author={Fujita, Shigeru},
    journal={FRB Phil. Business Review},
    volume={4},
    year={2010}
}
@article{rothstein2011unemployment,
    title={Unemployment insurance and job search in the {Great Recession}},
    author={Rothstein, Jesse},
    journal={NBER},
    volume={w17534},
    year={2011}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\defaultbibliography{mwecitations}
\defaultbibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}
\section{something}
First discuss \cite*{goossens93}.
\putbib
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}
\section{something else}
Now discuss \cite*{rothstein2011unemployment} and \cite*{fujita2010economic}.
\putbib
\end{bibunit}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Global bibliography}
\bibliography[mwecitations]

\end{document}
```

which outputs this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

There is no global bibliography and the name of the citation file is included erroneously. I'm trying to get a global bibliography that includes *every* citation from *every* bibunit at the end of the document. Per the [bibunits documentation](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/bibunits/bibunits.pdf):

> You can create a global bibliography as usual with the commands `\bibliography[〈BibTeX files〉]` and `\bibliographystyle[〈style〉]`. Use `\cite` and `\nocite` to generate citations that appear in the local bibliography.  Use `\cite*` and `\nocite*` inside a unit to generate citations for both the local and global bibliography.

As far as I can tell, I've applied this correctly. If I use `\bibliography` instead of `\bibliography[mwecitations]` (since I'm hoping to use the *default* .bib file without having to call it by name), I get the error

> ! Paragraph ended before `\bibliography` was complete.

What am I doing wrong? I compile the document with

```
xelatex mwe
bibtex bu1.aux
bibtex bu2.aux
xelatex mwe
xelatex mwe
```

I'm using `natbib` for the author-year citations.

Comment: I tyhink you have to replace `\bibliography[mwecitations]` with `\bibliography{mwecitations}`  (Not tested but easy to understand from your input and output)

Comment: @koleygr The documentation clearly uses a bracket `[` instead of a brace, but I'll try that.

Comment: I saw it there in your question after answered. But just some seconds later @Ulrike Fischer provided an answer using `{}` instead of `[]`... Anyway if it fail, you should try your way but including the extension (bib) too because 〈BibTeX files〉 supposed to be with their extension if no other way mentioned.

Comment: It is may be a typo as far as I checked. See section 3.3 on the documentation you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three errors: You have a typo (brackets instead of braces), the global \bibliographystyle is missing, and you didn't run bibtex on your main file.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[globalcitecopy]{bibunits}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{filecontents*}{mwecitations.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@article{fujita2010economic,
    title={Economic effects of the unemployment insurance benefit},
    author={Fujita, Shigeru},
    journal={FRB Phil. Business Review},
    volume={4},
    year={2010}
}
@article{rothstein2011unemployment,
    title={Unemployment insurance and job search in the {Great Recession}},
    author={Rothstein, Jesse},
    journal={NBER},
    volume={w17534},
    year={2011}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\defaultbibliography{mwecitations}
\defaultbibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}
\section{something}
First discuss \cite*{goossens93}.
\putbib
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}
\section{something else}
Now discuss \cite*{rothstein2011unemployment} and \cite*{fujita2010economic}.
\putbib
\end{bibunit}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Global bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mwecitations}

\end{document}
```

[image]