# Compiling process with chapterbib and subdirectories

Tags: bibtex, compiling, directory, chapterbib

Let's consider the following directory structure:

```
.
├── contents
│   ├── backmatter
│   │   ├── appendix.bib
│   │   └── appendix.tex
│   ├── frontmatter
│   │   ├── preface.bib
│   │   └── preface.tex
│   └── mainmatter
│       ├── chapter1.bib
│       ├── chapter1.tex
│       ├── chapter2.bib
│       └── chapter2.tex
└── main.tex
```

And the following main file:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[oneside, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sf = false, tt = false]{libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{contents/frontmatter/preface}
\mainmatter
\include{contents/mainmatter/chapter1}
\include{contents/mainmatter/chapter2}
\backmatter
\include{contents/backmatter/appendix}
\end{document}
```

**Question:** How to use the `chapterbib` package and compile the whole thing so that one bibliography section gets generated for every chapter at the end of every chapter? (I would like the explanation *with* **and** *without* `natbib` if that changes anything)

---

The preface:

```
% preface.tex
\chapter{Preface}

\section{Preface first section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{preface:ref1}

\section{Preface second section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{preface:ref2}

\section{Preface third section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{preface:ref3}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{preface}
```

and:

```
% preface.bib
@article{preface:ref1,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {Preface1},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{preface:ref2,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {Preface2},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{preface:ref3,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {Preface3},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}
```

The first chapter:

```
% chapter1.tex
\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First chapter first section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{chapter1:ref1}

\section{First chapter second section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{chapter1:ref2}

\section{First chapter third section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{chapter1:ref3}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{chapter1}
```

and:

```
% chapter1.bib
@article{chapter1:ref1,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {FirstChapter1},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{chapter1:ref2,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {FirstChapter2},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{chapter1:ref3,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {FirstChapter3},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}
```

The second chapter:

```
% chapter2.tex
\chapter{Second chapter}

\section{Second chapter first section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{chapter2:ref1}

\section{Second chapter second section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{chapter2:ref2}

\section{Second chapter third section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{chapter2:ref3}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{chapter2}
```

and:

```
% chapter2.bib
@article{chapter2:ref1,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {SecondChapter1},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{chapter2:ref2,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {SecondChapter2},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{chapter2:ref3,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {SecondChapter3},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}
```

The appendix:

```
% appendix.tex
\chapter*{Appendix}

\section*{Appendix first section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{appendix:ref1}

\section*{Appendix second section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{appendix:ref2}

\section*{Appendix third section}
\lipsum[1]\cite{appendix:ref3}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{appendix}
```

and:

```
% appendix.bib
@article{appendix:ref1,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {Appendix1},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{appendix:ref2,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {Appendix2},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}

@article{appendix:ref3,
    author  = {Someone}, 
    title   = {Appendix3},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = 2000,
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use biblatex + biber which makes this much easier?

Comment: I make my own compilation scripts and I would like to know how to do it from scratch.

Comment: Maybe like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300144