# Chapterwise references with overleaf and jabref

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf, jabref, chapterbib

I am writing my thesis using overleaf and jabref as the reference manager. I am also using LuaLatex for compiling. Right now I have separate bib file for each chapter and I am trying to get references at the end of each chapter. There are multiple references which are used in (may be) every chapter. Here is my minimized preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\input{chapter01}
\input{chapter02}
```

and then for my chapters;

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Introduction}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{chapter01}
```

and

```
\chapter{Theory}
\input{Theory}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{chapter02}
```

The problem is for the first chapter, it works perfectly. All the references are cited and they appear at the end of the chapter. However, for the second chapter only some of them are cited and others just look like "?"s. And the reference list is not even the relevant references. There are multiple duplicate questions asked on this topic,  I tried almost all of them, none of them seem to work. If anybody has an idea how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Make 2 chapter files: `chap1.tex` and `chap2.tex`, and 2 bib files: `bib1.bib` and `bib2.bib`. Save these files in your project folder on Overleaf. Make the main file: `TeXSE.tex` Compile `TeXSE.tex`.

`Chap1.tex` file:

```
\section{First section of chapter 1}

This is Chapter 1 from the input file chap1.tex.
    
This is a citation for Acemoglu (2000) \cite{acemoglu2000} from bib1.
    
Acemoglu (2012) \citep{acemoglu2012} is a citation for the second reference. 
    
The Reference list for introductory chapter appears next. 
    
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bib1}
```

`Chap2.tex` file:

```
\section{First section of chapter 2}

This is Chapter 2 from the input file chap2.tex. 

This is a citation for Acemoglu (2000) \cite{acemoglu2000} from bib2. 

Ackerberg (2006) \cite{ackerberg2006} is a citation for the second reference. 

The Reference list for the chapter appears next. 

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bib2}
```

`bib1.bib` file:

```
@article{acemoglu2000,
    title={The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
    author={Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
    year={2000},
    institution={National bureau of economic research}
}
@book{acemoglu2012,
    title={Why nations fail: the origins of power, prosperity and poverty},
    author={Acemoglu, Daron and Robinson, James A and Woren, Dan},
    volume={4},
    year={2012},
    publisher={SciELO Chile}
}
```

`bib2.bib` file:

```
@article{acemoglu2000,
    title={The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
    author={Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
    year={2000},
    institution={National bureau of economic research}
}
@article{ackerberg2006,
    title={Structural identification of production functions},
    author={Ackerberg, Daniel and Caves, Kevin and Frazer, Garth},
    year={2006}
}
```

Make the main document file, `TeXSE.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}   
                                          
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}          
\usepackage{chapterbib}                                        

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\include{Chap1}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\include{Chap2}

\end{document}
```

Upload each of these files to your project folder on Overleaf.

Compile `TeXSE.tex` gives (the chapter titles are omitted):

[image]

[image]

This is the same approach as described here: [Different bibliographies for each chapter with shared references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300144/) except that using `filecontents` to save the files does not create the example files on Overleaf. Here, I just avoided that by making 5 separate files. Welcome to TeX.SE.